# GAE: How to use ReferenceProperty in django forms?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-forms, referenceproperty

I'm playing around with google app engine a little but got stuck processing a POST request using a `ReferenceProperty`. I'm creating a dropdown menu from the existing categories like so:

```
<select name="mydropdown">
<label for="category">category:</label>
    {% for c in cats %}
        <option value={{ c.title }} name="category"> {{ c.title }} </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

The form has more fields to it:

```
<div>
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    {{ e_form.title }} 
</div>
....
```

The option value needs to be part of `{{ e_form }}`, in this case `{{ e_form.category }`. How can I establish such a cross reference? Or what would be a different good solution for my problem?

Have a look at my models (the `class CatForm()` is used elsewhere):

```
class Category(db.Model):
   title = db.StringProperty()
   slug = db.StringProperty()
   description = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)


class CatForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        exclude = ['slug']


class Entry(db.Model):
    category = db.ReferenceProperty(Category)
    author = db.UserProperty()
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    slug = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    body = db.TextProperty(required=True)
    published = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)


class EntryForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        exclude = ['published','updated']
```

Like this I can't create a form instance with my POST data. Well, I can create it but my selected category won't be in there.

```
def post(self):
   data = EntryForm(data=self.request.POST)
...
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but the field name comes from the `select` not the `option`, so in your HTML the name is `mydropdown`.

Comment: Ok, we're getting there - now I'm able to catch the incoming data even though I'm still getting a error `raise datastore_errors.BadKeyError('Invalid string key %s.' % encoded)`. That is obviously related to the ` ReferenceProperty`. Looking into that right now...

Comment: You probably want `{{ c.key }}` as the option value.

Comment: Actually you get it by default. I solved my problem by excluding the category from the `EntryForm()` and setting it's value manually. You do have to create an instance of `Category` though before you can add the value to `Entry()`. Thanks for thinking along!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the complete answer if someone wants to know. Like @Daniel said, the field name comes from the select not the option. So this is how the select should look like:

```
<select name="category">
    <label for="category">category:</label>
    {% for c in cats %}
       <option>{{ c.title }} </option>
    {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

You can either create an instance of the parent class using the category title

```
c = self.request.get("category")
cat_get = Category.all().filter("title =", c).get()
```

or use the key as the `option` name in the template like so:

```
<option name="{{ c.key }}">{{ c.title }} </option>
```

Then you can use the key directly to get the `Category` object.

```
    cat_obj = db.get(db.Key(key_name))
```

This is all the data I need to make a new entry. The `commit=False` keyword argument returns an object that hasn't been saved to the DB yet. That makes it possible to set single attributes manually. In this case the category. [See This link for details on the Django `save()`-method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method). To save the data the `put()`-method is used.

```
new_entry = form_data.save(commit=False)
new_entry.category = cat_get
new_entry.put()
```

Putting all the pieces together the handler could look like this.

```
class NewEntry(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        form_data =  EntryForm(self.request.POST)

        if form_data.is_valid():
            c = self.request.get("category")
            cat_get = Category.all().filter("title =", c).get()
            new_entry = form_data.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.category = cat_get
            new_entry.put()
            self.redirect("/main" )
        else:
            self.response.set_status(500)
```